# How can I support second-floor beams when replacing posts in the basement?

Tags: basement, framing

We are excavating our half basement and need to replace the support posts with new ones on new footings.  The problem is that 2 of the 3 posts also extend to the 2nd floor.  We can't just jack up the joists with temporary shores as in most cases because the beam would be unsupported.

The post goes from the footing block straight up to the 2nd floor and would not be supported by the joists except by nails around it.

[image]

[This video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=AL6dk2Hxp-U&t=19s) shows it in the first part.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. When you say you're replacing the posts you don't really mean that you're totally replacing the second floor posts, right? You'll just extend the existing ones? Edit your question to describe that better, please.

Comment: I would say that you should immediately put steel screw adjustable posts on both sides of the post you have excavated around because it looks like that soil could give way.

Comment: Wow. Yes! Dry soil like that tends to basically explode under unsupported pressure. I'd be nervous just being in that basement. Good catch, Jim.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, there is no way to do this all from the lower level. Add temporary support to the beams in the basement, then go up a floor to the main level and take the load off that post with temporary supports to transfer the load to those beams.

Comment: In order to place the shoring, footings must first be cast or cribbage placed on undisturbed soil for shoring to rest on.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the video - it appears that this gentleman has taken out the foundation wall these "posts" were on top of.  True there is no way to do what you are asking here.  I also believe comment above from Jim Stewart is true - but you cannot put posts on either side of the leftover foundation wall concrete as there is nothing under the beam but dirt now.  I would consult with an expert on such renovation in person, I've never before seen what you are doing here.